# Returning structures from functions. C

Tags: c, struct, return, structure

I am new to C and programming as a whole. I am trying to create a simple file validation program that reads in records from a file and sorts valid from invalid records. I have managed to achieve this but have run into problems when trying to return the structs for use in the main program.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <malloc.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAX 20

typedef struct data{
int ref; 
int serial;
char string[MAX+1]; 
}vaild,invalid;


int g = 1;
int e = 1;

void read(FILE *file);
void val(struct data* t);
void create_record(struct data* temp);
void create_error(struct data* temp);

void export_data(struct data* record, struct data* error);


int main(){
FILE *file = fopen("file.txt", "r");

if (file != NULL){
    read (file);
```

I want to be able to call the structures 'valid and 'invalid' from here inside the main function. Like the commented out printf function below.

```
    //printf("%i", valid[1].ref); <<<<<<<<<< I need to be able to play around with the structures from inside the main function!

    }

return 0;
}

void read(FILE *file){

    struct data* t = malloc(sizeof(struct data));

    char buf[1000];

    while(!feof(file)){
        fgets(buf, sizeof buf, file);
        sscanf(buf, "%d.%d.%s", &t->ref,  &t->serial,  t->string);

        val(t);

    }

}

void val (struct data* t){

    if((t->ref < 30)){
        struct data* valid = (struct data*) malloc(sizeof(struct data));

        valid = (struct data*)realloc(valid, g * sizeof(struct data));

        valid[g-1] = *t;

        if (valid == NULL){
            puts("Memory allocation error!");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
    printf("\nGOOD:%i.%i.%s\n", valid[g-1].ref, valid[g-1].serial,  valid[g-1].string);
    g++;
}
else{

    struct data* invalid = (struct data*) malloc(sizeof(struct data));

    invalid = (struct data*)realloc(invalid, e * sizeof(struct data));
    invalid[e-1] = *t;

    if ( invalid == NULL){
        puts("Memory allocation error!");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    printf("\nBAD:%i.%i.%s\n", invalid[e-1].ref, invalid[e-1].serial,  invalid[e-1].string);
    e++;
    }

}
```

I cant seem to be able to call the structures from within main by using the return functions, I feel I must be doing something really simple wrong. Getting pretty frustrated.

The input file is like so:

```
04.06.hello
09.65.test
88.55.string
27.12.qwerty
11.53.ytrewq
92.02.ecco
```

Everything else is working fine and there are no compiler errors. I have changed all the return types to void to make it less messy, I think I must be using them wrong.

Comment: What do you mean, "returning structures?"  All your functions are of type void.  They don't return anything.

Comment: *"but have run into problems"* - Which problems? Please be specific. Currently your question doesn't describe what is going wrong.

Comment: Note that you have some inconsistencies with `vaild` and `valid`.  It is unusual to give a structure type two names like `valid` and `invalid`.  Your code also uses `struct data` even though you've defined the types.

Comment: I have edited to make the explanation clearer. @JonathanLeffler What inconsistencies would they be?

Comment: At the top, you define one type and two aliases for the type: `typedef struct data { … } vaild, invalid;` and the spelling of `vaild` here is both unusual and not repeated.  Inside the `val()` function, you define local variables `struct data *valid = …;` and `struct data *invalid = …;` which hide the (corrected) typedef names at the top of the file.  Frankly, you'd do as well dropping the keyword `typedef` and the names `vaild` and `invalid` from the structure definition.

Comment: You also have a pair of unconventional array initializations. One is at: `struct data* valid = (struct data*) malloc(sizeof(struct data)); valid = (struct data*)realloc(valid, g * sizeof(struct data));` The first line allocates a single `struct data`; the second line reallocates that space to create an array of size `g` entries. You should change the `malloc()` to allocate `g * sizeof(struct data)` bytes (or, better, `g * sizeof(*valid)`) and drop the `realloc()`. However, you are never passing the point back, nor is there a global variable to initialize, so you're effectively leaking memory.

Comment: I did my best to provide a complete working example :) check that

Answer (score 1):

Found your problem

```
void val (struct data* t){

        if((t->ref < 30)){
            struct data* valid = (struct data*) malloc(sizeof(struct data));

            valid = (struct data*)realloc(valid, g * sizeof(struct data));

            valid[g-1] = *t;

            if (valid == NULL){
                puts("Memory allocation error!");
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
            }
        printf("\nGOOD:%i.%i.%s\n", valid[g-1].ref, valid[g-1].serial,  valid[g-1].string);
        g++;
    }
    else{

        struct data* invalid = (struct data*) malloc(sizeof(struct data));

        invalid = (struct data*)realloc(invalid, e * sizeof(struct data));
        invalid[e-1] = *t;

        if ( invalid == NULL){
            puts("Memory allocation error!");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }

        printf("\nBAD:%i.%i.%s\n", invalid[e-1].ref, invalid[e-1].serial,  invalid[e-1].string);
        e++;
        }

    }
```

In above code when you define valid and invalid inside If and else if , scope of these variables are inside those if conditions. So you will get "valid not defined" error.

Try this

```
struct data* val(struct data* t){

    if((t->ref < 30)){
        struct data* valid_file = (struct data*) malloc(sizeof(struct data));

        valid_file = (struct data*)realloc(valid_file, g * sizeof(struct data));

        valid_file[g-1] = *t;

        if (valid_file == NULL){
            puts("Memory allocation error!");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
       printf("\nGOOD:%i.%i.%s\n", valid_file[g-1].ref, valid_file[g-1].serial,  valid_file[g-1].string);
       g++;
       return valid_file;
    }

    // Will come when result is invalid
    struct data* invalid_file = (struct data*) malloc(sizeof(struct data));

    invalid_file = (struct data*)realloc(invalid_file, e * sizeof(struct data));
    invalid_file[e-1] = *t;

    if ( invalid_file == NULL){
        puts("Memory allocation error!");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    printf("\nBAD:%i.%i.%s\n", invalid_file[e-1].ref, invalid_file[e-1].serial,  invalid_file[e-1].string);
    e++;
    return invalid_file;
}
```

Note - Changed valid and invalid to different variable names to separate struct name definitions.

Complete working example :)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <malloc.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAX 20

typedef struct data{
int ref; 
int serial;
char string[MAX+1]; 
}vaild,invalid;


int g = 1;
int e = 1;

struct data* read(FILE *file);
struct data* val(struct data* t);
void create_record(struct data* temp);
void create_error(struct data* temp);

void export_data(struct data* record, struct data* error);


int main(){
FILE *file = fopen("file.txt", "r");

if (file != NULL){
     struct data* answ=read (file);

     printf("%i \n", answ->ref);
    }

return 0;
}

struct data* read(FILE *file){

    struct data* t = malloc(sizeof(struct data));

    char buf[1000];

    while(!feof(file)){
        fgets(buf, sizeof buf, file);
        sscanf(buf, "%d.%d.%s", &t->ref,  &t->serial,  t->string);

        val(t);
    }
    return t;
}

struct data* val(struct data* t){

        if((t->ref < 30)){
            struct data* valid_file = (struct data*) malloc(sizeof(struct data));

            valid_file = (struct data*)realloc(valid_file, g * sizeof(struct data));

            valid_file[g-1] = *t;

            if (valid_file == NULL){
                puts("Memory allocation error!");
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
            }
           printf("\nGOOD:%i.%i.%s\n", valid_file[g-1].ref, valid_file[g-1].serial,  valid_file[g-1].string);
           g++;
           return valid_file;
        }

        // Will come when result is invalid
        struct data* invalid_file = (struct data*) malloc(sizeof(struct data));

        invalid_file = (struct data*)realloc(invalid_file, e * sizeof(struct data));
        invalid_file[e-1] = *t;

        if ( invalid_file == NULL){
            puts("Memory allocation error!");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }

        printf("\nBAD:%i.%i.%s\n", invalid_file[e-1].ref, invalid_file[e-1].serial,  invalid_file[e-1].string);
        e++;
        return invalid_file;
    }
```

Comment: 1. Do not need to cast the `malloc` 2. Why do a `realloc` straight after `malloc`?

Answer (score 0):

Returning a struct in C is acceptable when the struct is small. Otherwise you'd be better off using pointers.

The snippet below is a simple example that shows you how to return a struct. 
Same rules apply as returning any other data type (e.g., int, double, ...), return types need to match and the function needs to have a return statement.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct {
    int x;
    int y;
} Point;

Point init_point(Point p, int x, int y) {
    p.x = x;
    p.y = y;
    return p;
}

void main() {
    Point p1, p2;
    printf("%d, %d\n", p1.x, p1.y);
    printf("%d, %d\n", p2.x, p2.y);
    p1 = init_point(p1, 55, 10);
    printf("%d, %d\n", p1.x, p1.y);
    printf("%d, %d\n", p2.x, p2.y);

    p2 = init_point(p2, 10000, 190);
    printf("%d, %d\n", p1.x, p1.y);
    printf("%d, %d\n", p2.x, p2.y);
}
```

The result is :

-1080464084, -1080464264

1, -1080464092

55, 10

1, -1080464092

55, 10

10000, 190

Comment: You need to recommend it's in C99 or later.

Comment: Not to doubt you or anything, but I tried to "break" my code using "gcc -std=c89 -pedantic -Wall..." this didn't produce any warnings.
So I added a function to the code to make sure gcc catches of the version differences (to test my usage)
bla() {
return 4;
}
And indeed with C99 it added "Return type defaults to ‘int’ [enabled by default]", which did not appear with C89. 
Either I am not using gcc correctly to enforce this. 
==>again, I thought my code would "break"/generate compiler warnings with C89? Is gcc not strictly adhering to it? I thought the -std option would produce some warnings.

Comment: Ooops, sorry! It was C89.

Comment: Aha...at least I am using gcc correctly hahaha :)
Sadly, I don't believe the current gcc supports earlier standards anymore :(
Thanks for clarifying though :)